How to connect SQL queries to PowerBI
I studied PowerBI and SQL queries seperately but now I want to create an end to end project combining sql queries with PowerBI. I couldn't find any references to this online.
I don't know what people do after querying the data in SQL. Do they add it to visualization tools like PowerBI?
I tried connecting SQL queried tables with PowerBI and it worked. but still I don't know why it is used.

It is used for reporting and representing data in visual rather than tabular view. Also for performing calculations using this data, e.g. you have Order Number and Order Amount, and you want to see the count of Orders for current month - you count the number of Order Numbers. Or/And the current month sales amounts. It is much easier to understand aggregated data. It depends on the business type/report type what information would be analyzed. There are various courses that are using open databases to train you how to start and finish a Power BI report.

I think this covers it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/mysql-database

**
EDITED
**
Connect Database to Power BI:
Use Power BI’s Get Data feature to connect to a database (e.g., SQL Server, MySQL).
Choose either Import Mode or DirectQuery Mode depending on the need for real-time data or efficiency.
Import Mode and Query Folding:
In Import Mode, data is stored locally in Power BI, and you can improve performance using Query Folding.
Query folding pushes data transformations (filtering, joining, etc.) back to the source database, meaning Power BI receives already transformed data.
To check if folding is happening: Open Power Query Editor > Right-click the last step in the Applied Steps pane > Select View Native Query (if available).
Imagine we have a table named SalesData with columns: OrderID, CustomerName, OrderDate, Product, Quantity, and SalesAmount. We want to filter data to include only orders from 2023 and remove the CustomerName column.
Query:
 SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, Product, Quantity, SalesAmount
FROM SalesData WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = 2023

Common transformations that support query folding include:

Removing/Renaming columns
Merging/Joining queries
Pivot/Unpivot
Numeric calculations

DirectQuery Mode:
In DirectQuery Mode, Power BI sends queries directly to the database every time you interact with a report, providing real-time data but potentially slower performance.
Write custom SQL queries in the Advanced Option while setting up the connection to optimize data retrieval:
SQL
SELECT PlayerName, Runs, Wickets FROM PlayerStats WHERE MatchDate >= '2024-01-01'
Limitations:

Not all sources and transformations support query folding.
DirectQuery Mode may limit some DAX functions and be slower due to
constant querying.
Query folding and SQL optimization help reduce data load and
improve report performance, especially in large datasets.


Hi @shailabh Binjola, I appreciate your time to answer this question, I would like to suggest you to improve on your answer by giving relevant examples and pointing out a step by step instruction to improve and make it more understandable.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@GowthamS sure!! thanks for the suggestion , i will surely keep that in mind for future solutions.
